# How to Add Content using :after?

Tags: css

I want to add some text after this using CSS:

```css
div#option-box-ymq-variant-1.ymq-options-box ymq-options-box-15 ymq-shopify-option-box :after {
  content: "Testing";
}
```

```html
<div class="ymq-options-box ymq-options-box-15  ymq-shopify-option-box " id="option-box-ymq-variant-1" data-type="15" data-id="-ymq-variant-1" data-ymq-add-to-cart="1" data-name="ymq-option2" data-label="Modo de Color" data-onetime="0" data-class="ymq-attrib-ymq-variant-1"
  name="option-box-ymq-variant-Modo de Color">Div</div>
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm new to coding.

Comment: `div#option-box-ymq-variant-1:after{content:'test';}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match multiple classes you need to use `.` instead of   (space):

```css
div#option-box-ymq-variant-1.ymq-options-box.ymq-options-box-15.ymq-shopify-option-box::after {
  content: "Testing";
}
```

```html
<div class="ymq-options-box ymq-options-box-15  ymq-shopify-option-box " id="option-box-ymq-variant-1" data-type="15" data-id="-ymq-variant-1" data-ymq-add-to-cart="1" data-name="ymq-option2" data-label="Modo de Color" data-onetime="0" data-class="ymq-attrib-ymq-variant-1"
  name="option-box-ymq-variant-Modo de Color">
```

Your previous selector:

```css
div#option-box-ymq-variant-1.ymq-options-box ymq-options-box-15 ymq-shopify-option-box :after
```

Was selecting the after pseudo element of nothing that was a child of an element of type `ymq-shopify-option-box` (which doesn't exist) etc. as a space in a selector is a [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

**Note: Use two colons for pseudo elements**
This is the current way of differentiating a pseudo element (like before and after) from a pseudo class.

**Note: Pseudo element text is for styling and not content**
Adding a bit of text or styling in pseudo elements can be very useful, but be aware that the text is not part of the DOM and may get missed for example by screen readers so don't totally rely on them to convey vital information on their own, they are more of a useful embellishment.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed and informative answer Haworth! Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you select wrong

```
div#option-box-ymq-variant-1:after{
    content: 'test';
}
```

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: check that `div` tag have closed. in your question the `div` tag is not closed.